# Visualizing a 3D scene in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl

I need to visualize 3D models consisting of ~100.000 triangles in a Qt application. Colors, zoom in/out and rotation are required. The solution must work under Linux and Windows.

Should I use OpenGL directly or would you recommend using a certain library? There are game engines (ClanLib,...), but I'm not sure if they are appropriate at all. A good point to start would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are thinking about creating a big application do not use openscenegraph. Openscenegraph has major issues.. It hijacks opengl context (assumes no one else uses opengl with you), lacks documentation, has some issues with lights in Viewer, and has some performance issues for large number of openscenegraph nodes. Also the project is not much active... If you are creating a medium ou small app, though, use it for sure!

Answer (score 4):

You should consider the [QtOpenGL](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtopengl.html) module that comes with Qt. Take a look at the [provided examples](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/examples-opengl.html) and look on YouTube for [Qt OpenGL](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Qt+OpenGL) to find a few screencasts.

In Qt 4.8 that was just released a few days ago, QtOpenGL [added support for multi-threading](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/06/03/threaded-opengl-in-4-8/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenGL calls directly in a `QGLWidget`, so don't think that you may be constrained by Qt's OpenGL support.

Comment: Qt's opengl support is just the widget and a few cross platform convenience wrappers around buffers and settings - it's pretty much still raw openGL programming

Answer (score 2):

You can do this yourself in QtOpenGL but you might find using a scenegraph is easier.
[Open scenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org) plays nicely with Qt